# Advantage of central moment over moment?

Tags: moments

Is there any advantage of using "central moments" over "moments" when approximating a distribution to a known distribution using moment matching? I have noticed that in lot of papers.

Comment: Since central moments and regular moments are related via linear transformations, there is no theoretical advantage of one form over the other. In some cases, there might be a small computational advantage in beginning with one form versus the other.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, that looks like it addresses the OP's question pretty directly. I wonder if you'd like to switch it to an answer from a comment.

Answer (score 5):

Following the suggestion by gung:

Central moments $\mu_n$ are related to moments $m_n$ through linear transformations:

$$\mu_n = E[(X-\mu)^n] = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}(-\mu)^{n-i}E[X^i]
= \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}(-\mu)^{n-i}m_i.$$

An adaptation, emendation, and incorporation
of a proposal by @Flav for an improved statement:

One theoretical advantage to central moments is that they are invariant to translations along the $x$ axis: the central moments of $Y = X + a$ 
are the same as the central moments of $X$. From a computational perspective, 
in some cases, (non-central) moments are slightly easier to calculate than
central moments, while in other cases, the central moments are slightly
easier to calculate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I solved a moment matching problem and have seen that expression for central moment is much simpler than that of moment

Comment: @prasenjit: Don't forget to designate this as your answer if it turns out to be the best.