Expected value of the product of three random variables
For two dependent random variables we have:
$$Cov[X, Y] = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$$
So that $E[XY] = E[X]E[Y] + Cov[X, Y]$
In case of three arbitrarily correlated random variables $(X, Y, Z)$, is it possible to write $E[XYZ]$ as a function of $E[X]E[Y]E[Z]$ and an additional term $r$ (which is a function of paiwise covariances of the original three variables)?
That is, is it possible to obtain the following?
$$ E[XYZ]= E[X]E[Y]E[Z] + r $$
If not, can $E[XYZ]$ still be written as a function of $ E[X]E[Y]E[Z]$ and other terms?

Depending on what you mean by "general form," I believe your question is answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155007.  You might also find https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67240 to be helpful.

What you are asking for is like can the joint distribution of $(X, Y, Z)$ be determined by all bivariate marginal distributions, which is of course impossible.  The bivariate case you mentioned is trivial, because you are expressing a bivariate property $E[XY]$ in terms of another bivariate property $\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y)$.

Let $W = YZ$, such that
$$
\begin{align}
E[XYZ] &= E[XW] \\
&= E[X]E[W] + \textrm{Cov}(X, W) \\
&= E[X]E[YZ] + \textrm{Cov}(X, YZ) \\
&= E[X](E[Y]E[Z] + \textrm{Cov}(Y, Z)) + \textrm{Cov}(X, YZ) \\
&= E[X]E[Y]E[Z] + E[X]\textrm{Cov}(Y, Z) + \textrm{Cov}(X, YZ)
\end{align}
$$
Is this what you're looking for?

I suspect "function of pairwise covariances" should have ended "of the original three variables."  Lurking here is the unavoidable fact that the requested expectation is a third moment and so we should not expect it to be reducible solely to second moments of the original distribution -- and perhaps that's the thrust of the question.

@whuber Indeed. My answer was intentionally directed more towards answering the question "...is there a general form for $E[XYZ]$?".

I would maintain that a correct, general, and revealing answer would not offer some specific reformulation, but instead would point out that $E[XYZ]$ is one component of a rank-3 tensor (the multivariate third moment tensor), whence any equivalent formula must be a linear combination of other components of that tensor (of which you have exhibited one example out of the infinitely many that are possible).

thanks to both, the first comment is correct, but also the final answer (since I was also asking for a way to write E[XYZ] that would use E[X]E[Y]E[Z] and any other terms. I have rephrased the question to clarify this better. I accept the answer
